# add_rewrite_rule() issue with parent/child/child page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a **parent/child** and another **parent/child/child** pages. I have 2 separate page templates for both pages and the following add_rewrite_rule() code in place:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^user/dashboard/([^/]*)/?’, 'index.php?pagename=user/dashboard&profile=$matches[1]', 'top' );

add_rewrite_rule( '^user/dashboard/billing/([^/]*)/?’, 'index.php?pagename='user/dashboard/billing&profile=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

The first one (i.e. parent/child) works fine but the 2nd one (i.e parent/child/child) is not working. Meaning when I go to the **parent/child/child** page, it is using the template of the parent/child page and not the one assigned to itself.

If I comment out the first add_rewrite_rule() line, it works as expected. Seems like the first one is overriding the 2nd one.

I have tried flushing the rewrite rules manually by going to settings > permalinks.

I have even tried to change the order of the rewriting rules i.e. I tried registering the **parent/child/child** path before **parent/child** rule and then flushed the rules manually. But that also didn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order, first comes the more specific add_rewrite_rule , then the general one, try this

```
   add_rewrite_rule( '^user/dashboard/billing/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=user/dashboard/billing&profile=$matches[1]', 'top' );
   add_rewrite_rule( '^user/dashboard/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=user/dashboard&profile=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

After the change, you have to turn off/on the permalinks in the settings to clear the cache.

Comment: Hi, I tried this already. You can see at the end of my details I already mentioned it (:

Comment: I try this on my demo and its works, intstall on your site Query Monitor plugin and check what rewrite works at billing page

Comment: Sure, let me try again..thanks
!

Comment: thank you, you saved me!